Was Ganesha created out of dirt by Parvati?
I heard that Parvati created Ganesha out of dirt. Is there any scriptural reference to it? What was the origin of Ganesha?

Out of powder of pulses made wet and rubbed on skin to cleanse the body before bathing with water.

@Narasimham That is what you are saying. Siva Purana does not say that. See the answer.

Maybe. Heard such stories when a kid... the dal paste made from seeds, they grow from plants which in turn grow out of soil. Since the purpose of taking bath is cleansing, dirt will not be directly applied on the body for cleaning.

There are multiple stories required to birth, one of them is as you ask. As per lalitopakhyana, Parvati and Shiva looked at each other to destroy the Vighna Yantra created by Bandasura. So, Vigneshwara was created.

@Kanthri What is Lalitopakhyana?

Please see shloka 67 https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/lalitopakhyana-lalita-mahatmya/d/doc362965.html

There could be many versions of Ganesha’s birth story due to Kalpa-bheda but the story where Parvari created him from her body dirt is mentioned in Shiva Purana: Rudra-saṃhitā (4): Kumāra-khaṇḍa: Chapter 13 - The birth of Gaṇeśa:

Brahmā said:—

Due to the difference of Kalpas, the story of the birth of Gaṇeśa is told in different ways. According to one account he is born of the great lord. His head looked at by Śani was cut off and an elephant’s head was put on him.

Now we narrate the story of the birth of Gaṇeśa in Śvetakalpa when his head was cut off by the merciful Śiva.





“There must be a servant of my own who will be expert in his duties. He must not stray from my behest even a speck.”

Thinking thus the goddess created a person with all the characteristics, out of the dirt[3] from her body.

He was spotless and handsome in every part of his body. He was huge in size and had all brilliance, strength and valour.


22-23. She gave him various clothes and ornaments. She blessed him with benediction and said—“You are my son. You are my own. I have none else to call my own”.

